# How to get other array value after NSCaseInsensitiveSearch

Tags: objective-c, iphone, search, collectionview

I have a question here. In textDidChange function, i have NSMutableArray _setItem2 with "name","image","price" columns. And in this case, I able to search by "Name" column via sample code as below.

However, i would like to present my other columns value such as price and image after search filtering. How can i do that? Please help.

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
{

    if(text.length == 0)
    {
        isFiltered = FALSE;
        [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }
    else
    {
        isFiltered = true;     
        filteredTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (NSDictionary *item in _setItem2) {

            NSString *name = [item objectForKey:@"name"];
            NSRange nameRange = [name rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (nameRange.location != NSNotFound) {
                [filteredTableData addObject:name];           
            }
        }
    }

    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

And here is my cellForItemAtIndexPath function

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    DCListGridCell *cell = nil;
    cell = (_isSwitchGrid) ? [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:DCListGridCellID forIndexPath:indexPath] : [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:DCSwitchGridCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(isFiltered)
    {
        NSString *str1 = [filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //HOW CAN I SHOW IMAGE AND PRICE HERE??? NOW THE VALUE IS WRONG
        //==============================================================
        //cell.productImage = [[_setItem2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] image];
        cell.productName = [filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //cell.productPrice =  [[_setItem2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] price];

    }
    else
    {
        cell.productImage = [_setItem[indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"image"];
        cell.productName = [_setItem[indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"];
        cell.productPrice = [_setItem[indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"price"];
    }



    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Replace `[filteredTableData addObject:name];` with `[filteredTableData addObject:item];` then you can do `cell.productImage = [[_setItem2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"]; cell.productName = [[_setItem2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];`

Comment: Hi Larme, I tested your suggestion but the result is wrong. Result will be different compare with what I key in.

Comment: Hi Larme, it's work if cell.productName = [[_setItem2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"]; change to cell.productName = [[filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"]

Comment: My bad, I meant in fact `filteredTableData` instead of `_setItem2`.

Comment: Thx Larme for your comments!